# Setting environment variables for system users

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, login

I have a couple of system users that have no password set, login disabled and no home directories. They are used solely to run FastCGI processes for a couple of websites.

I want to avoid hard coding in sensitive data into the source code such as passwords and wanted to use environment variables instead so the question is how do you set environment variables for system users with no home directory and no login ability.

Normally I'd just put them in ~/.bashrc but obviously that won't work. I also can't put them in /etc/bashrc since that would mean all users would see the sensitive information.

Has anyone got any suggestions at all? This is on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS if that makes a difference.

Edit: As per the comment below I'm using Nginx for the HTTP server.

Comment: You might want to say what server you are using, since there is more than one that implements fastcgi and this can possibly be done via the server (e.g., I'd guess `mod_env` could do this for apache).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add a file to `/etc/profile.d/` to set variables based on `$UID`.  If you want to fine tune things more based on groups, see `man id`.

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 666 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, didn't know you could do this. As per your comment above though I am using Nginx as my HTTP server.

Comment: Interesting choice of UID. I'm guessing this is the standard `demon` user :D

Comment: How are you going to prevent other users from seeing this information? The scripts in `profile.d` need to be world readable.

Comment: @tripleee `if [ $UID -eq 666 ]; then . /etc/somedaemon/env.sh; fi`

Answer (score -1):

`chmod +a "username deny read" filename`